# IP changed inside Kali terminal, remote desktop connection refuses to connect to new IP

Tags: networking, terminal, remote-desktop

I have Kali installed in my WSL2 and when I was goofing around, I got to know I can change my IP address from the terminal.

But I forgot the remote desktop connection was using that IP to show that desktop to me. After I ran, Kali GUI crashed. Now, even if I enter the new IP address, the remote desktop connection gives the error.

What shall I do?

Comment: "New"+"Kali" is indeed a recipe for disaster.

Comment: WSL is NOT a virtual machine and was not made to run Kali.  Get a proper Virtual Machine App. My own Kali machine works great.

Comment: What error are you getting?